# Is the ENS light-client friendly?

Tags: light-clients, eth-lightwallet, ens

I am building an application that needs to verify the validity of ENS names as given by a resolver. Can resolvers attach a short proof to cryptographically guarantee that a given ENS name does indeed map to the corresponding Ethereum address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Pacia from the OpenBazaar team implemented [ens-lite](https://github.com/cpacia/ens-lite) which is a light-client resolver for the ENS.